# Как отсортировать массив объектов через localeCompare()?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Как с помощью `localComparse()` мне отсортировать `email`, так чтобы те у кого отличаются только цифры, становились в порядке возрастания?

Я пытался сделать чтото в этом роде:

```js
carsOwner = {
  data: [{
      car: "BMW",
      email: "jodofoufrotei11@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      car: "JAC",
      email: "frakaceinoillu29@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      car: "BMW",
      email: "jodofoufrotei71@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      car: "Tesla",
      email: "jodofoufrotei5@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      car: "Tesla",
      email: "jodofoufrotei1@gmail.com"
    },
  ]
}

function SortArray(x, y) {
  return x.email.localeCompare(y.email, 'kn');
}

const a = carsOwner.data.sort(SortArray);

console.log(a);
```

Но получаю совсем не то что хотелось бы + не понимаю как таким способом оно ходит по всем элементам массива и сравнивает их

Хотелось бы посмотреть на решение и получить ссылочку на ресурс (не мдн) где хорошо описана эта функция, заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: В MDN очень подробное объяснение, чем он вам не нравится?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Хотелось бы больше сложных примеров

Comment: А зачем? Там объясняется самая база, которая вам нужна, чтобы выполнить задачу. (Это база)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Спасибо за базу, дружище, очень помог наставлением )

Answer (score 0):

Отдельное спасибо [@NNL993](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1436840/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-localecompare/1436916#comment2563397_1436840), который помог мне дальше разобраться.

Вобщем решение заключается в том, чтобы массив отсортировать с данной функцией:

```
function sortToSort(x, y) {
      return x.email.localeCompare(y.email, "en", { numeric: true });
    }

    data.sort() // Результат отсортированный массив, в котором email отсортирован и по алфавиту и по нумерации
```